# Conditionally returning result from a plugin

Tags: add-on-development, php, plugin

I'm writing a custom plugin to tap into an external database, and I'm getting the overall results I want. However, I want to wrap my *return values* around a conditional to avoid processing unnecessary queries further down the line - this bit doesn't seem to be working :-/

Basically I want to check whether the current date is Christmas Day. So I have this early on in my logic:

```
    if($date[2]=="25" && $date[1]=="12") {
        $this->return_data = '<p>Sorry, there are no sailings on Christmas Day.</p>';
    }
```

If it is 25/12, then obviously output the above message and ignore the rest of the plugin, otherwise run the SQL and return a timetable.

Whats happening is (when I change the date to today) it continues through the plugin, always outputting the timetable, presumably because I've nothing to *stop* the plugin after it returns the data in this conditional.

Do I need to wrap this in an if/else structure? Or can I *break* the processing somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After setting the return data, you need to [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) program control to the Template class, which ends execution of the current method.

```
if ($date[2] == 25 && $date[1] == 12)
{
      $this->return_data = '<p>Sorry, there are no sailings on Christmas Day.</p>';
      return;
}
```

Incidentally, it isn't necessary to set the `$return_data` class property unless your plugin only operates in its [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). So most plugin/module methods can simply return their output:

```
if ($date[2] == 25 && $date[1] == 12)
{
      return '<p>Sorry, there are no sailings on Christmas Day.</p>';
}
```